# Javascript issue maintaining history after browser refresh?

Tags: javascript

```
var _history = new Array();
var _index=-1;
function updateHistory(shapeparam)
{
    _index = _index + 1;    
    _history.splice(_index,_history.length);
    _history.push(shapeparam);
}
```

From the above code i can maintain history without refresh it is working fine.
I want to make availiable the values even after refresh, 
please help me whether it is possible using javascript cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var _history = getCookie("history");
_history=_history?_history.split(","):[];
var _index=-1;
function updateHistory(shapeparam)
{
    _index = _index + 1;    
    _history.splice(_index,_history.length);
    _history.push(shapeparam);
    setCookie("history",_history.join(","));
}
```